# Automatic Re-direct

Tags: redirect

I set up an automatic redirect to redirect my sharepoint site to an outside URL. I want to go back and take out the redirect and edit the site. The problem is that every time I go to the sharepoint site it redirects me to the outside URL. Is there a way I can turn off the automatic redirect so that I can get back to the site? If I go through the site content and structure I'm still redirected.

I put in the redirect by adding a web part.

Comment: Can you try removing the web part by appending this to the page's URL to go directly to edit mode? "?PageView=Shared&ToolPaneView=2" (wtihout the quotes)

Comment: Post that as an answer so it can be upvoted (as it is the correct answer)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the web part by appending this to the page's URL to go directly to edit mode:

"?PageView=Shared&ToolPaneView=2"  (without the quotes)